# Custom return-type from JPA Repository Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to return only some objects of an entity class, since the primary key is not present in the data I require I can give my entity as return type.
Also tried creating another view-class, only classes on entity package is recognized by repository.

Tried Wild card of List<?> this gives only values, I want both Keys and values.

So I tried this, It gives the correct result, just wondering is there any better way ??

```
public interface JobRepository extends Repository<Job, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT j.employee_id,e.employee_name,e.employee_email, COUNT(*) as count FROM job j INNER join employee e on j.employee_id=e.employee_id GROUP BY j.employee_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>> getEmployeeCount();
}
```

this is the output.

```
[{
    "employee_name": "Employee 1",
    "employee_id": 1,
    "employee_email": "employee1@gmail.com",
    "count": 2
}]
```

this is the database structure

[image]

Comment: You can use projections, instead of this nested map. Just google it, there are lots of guides, [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections) for example. The topic has been covered on SO as well, you should not have problems finding resources on it.

Comment: I'm new to this; Ive joined table, ie, Job Entity and Employee Entity. I need the count of employee appeared on Job table. Tried projection and got output as
    {
        "employee": null
    },